# Merge "tasks" and "to-do"

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

Another day, another merge-request...

Investigating the [tasks](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tasks) (x14), it seems mainly to address [to-do](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/to-do) (x10), with maybe 4 exceptions rather relating to [task-manager] (x30).

Suggestion, as usually: Merge the two, and make one of them a synonym to the other. Re-tag the mentioned 4 exceptions to "task-manager".

As for [task-manager](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/task-manager) (x30) and [multitasking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multitasking) (x12) I'm not sure what to recommend. While both are clearly related, they represent different points of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly some of the "tasks" questions need re-tagging.

I'm not convinced, though, that "tasks" should be a synonym of "to-do". That Android has "task managers" and "task killers" strongly implies that "tasks" = "running Android processes".

It seems that "tasks" is just one of those ambiguous terms we should steer people away from. I suppose that as long as there is a "task-manager", the tag auto-suggest will guide people to the right tag.

Comment: I thought about that, and this was what made me uncertain. Maybe we "lock" [tag:tasks] so it cannot be used (there was a possibility as far as I remember), and instead provide "tasklist"? Or simply lock it away, as there are not so many questions using it either.

Comment: Tags can be "blacklisted" but that's just for extreme cases.

Comment: But I guess what we agree on is: questions tagged "tasks" *AND* "to-do" should get the "tasks" tag removed?

Comment: I'm leaning that way, but I'd like to see if anyone has any strong reasoning for either direction.

Comment: My few reasons: 1) reduce ambiguosity (reason for my last comment), 2) make things easier to find (re-tag; those are only tagged "tasks" are harder to find) and 3) concentrate stuff to make way for the Generalist badge xD